# what's wrong with my dahlia blossoms?

Tags: diseases, container-gardening

[image: sick dahlia blossom]Hi,

For the first month I grew this dahlia, it bloomed abundantly and appeared healthy. Now, some petals are twisted and brownish, and some buds don't fully open. Other buds appear fine. Can someone with more dahlia experience diagnose the problem?

Thanks

Jeff
enter image description here